# Errors to apply flex syntax to table with mobile view screen

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to apply the flex-css to the table so it will become responsive according to variation in screen size.
But It is not getting properly fit when tested in mobile size screen.

This is my code for that,

```
<mat-card fxLayout="column" 
           fxLayout.xs="column" 
          >
<div class="link"><a href="localhost:4201/" target="_blank">Go To Application</a></div>
<div>
<h3 ><strong>Welcome To Rockefeller </strong></h3>
    <p> Please Choose proper option to manage Organization .Navigation options will become available after doing so.</p>

</div>
<div  class="table" fxFlex="2 2 calc(10em + 10px)">
<table>


                    <tr>
                    <td >
                        <button class="entrInstbtn" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialogModifyOrg()" >Modify Organization Attributes</button>

                    </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td >
                        <button class="entrInstbtn" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="deleteOrg()" >Delete Organization</button>

                    </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td><button class="anchorelement" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialogForAddUser()">Add User</button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>   

                    <tr>        
                            <td><button class="anchorelement" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialogViewUser()">View/Edit User Information</button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>                
                    <td >
                        <button class="entrInstbtn" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialogUploadData()">Upload Data</button>

                    </td>
                    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</mat-card>
```

This is CSS ,I am using for this,

```
       mat-card{
    width:auto;
    height:550px;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
p{
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-spacing:1px;
    color:#0c0c28;
}


h3{
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.entrInstbtn{

    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.anchorelement{
    color:white;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

strong, mat-form-field, mat-select{
    color:#0c0c28;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.link{
    float:right;
    color:#0c0c28;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:85%;
}

.mat-raised-button{
    width:50%;
    border-radius:15px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:65%;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:400px ){

    .mat-raised-button{
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:9px;
        width:90%;
        margin-left:0%;
    }

    .link{
        margin-left:45%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:401px) and (max-width:600px){

    .mat-raised-button{
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:10px;
        width:75%;
        margin-left:20%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:601px and max-width:900px){

    .mat-raised-button{
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:11px;
        width:45%;
        margin-left:15%;
    }
}
```

This is snap shot in Desktop view,

[image]

this is snap shot in Mobile view,

[image]

Please any one help to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem with the code you posted, the styling and content is different than in the screenshots you posted though. Are you able to post the full HTML / CSS for your page so we can reproduce the issue shown in your screenshots?

Comment: See..now I have edited my whole code.

Answer (score 0):

A codepen with your code looks good to me:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/JLLMbq

Any possibility you forgot to add a viewport meta tag to the head of your document

```
<head>  
...  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
...  
</head>
```

or that's it's browser related?

If you haven't already done so, check with another browser. Browser support for flexbox is good except for IE
https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Or if you could share the URL of the page, that might help as well.